# How can I use regex on an attribute value in cy.get()?

Tags: javascript, regex, attributes, cypress

The application has list of items in a table and items have `[id=item[0].setupCost, id=item[1].setupCost, id=item[2].setupCost]` etc.

There's a functionality to add items also, so the index keeps on increasing.

I want to get input field regardless of using magic numbers. For eg `(cy.get('[id=item[some_regex].setupCost]')`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The regex that applies is `\[id="item\[\d+\].setupCost\]`.

Enclose the regex in forward slashes, not quotes.

```js
cy.get(/\[id="item\[\d+\].setupCost\]/)
```

#### But don't use it

This syntax is **undocumented** - it works (in Cypress v9.5.0) but it only returns one result.

So if you want to count your items, this will fail

```js
cy.get(/\[id="item\[\d+\].setupCost\]/)
  .its('length')
  .should('eq', 3)   // ❌
```

---

#### Partial attribute selector

If you want to use partial attribute selectors, this is strongest as it includes `.setupCost`

Ref [Find the element with id that starts with "local-" and ends with "-remote"](https://docs.cypress.io/api/commands/get#Find-the-element-with-id-that-starts-with-local-and-ends-with-remote)

```js
cy.get('[id^="item"][id$=".setupCost"]')  // use "starts-with" and "ends-with" selectors
```

This succeeds with the count test

```js
cy.get('[id^="item"][id$=".setupCost"]')
  .its('length')
  .should('eq', 3)   // ✅
```

Answer (score 3):

In case you need another answer:

You can use a regex if you add a jQuery extension.

It works because Cypress uses jQuery internally, and you can modify selector behavior by extending jQuery.

```js
it('finds multiple ids by regex', () => {

  const $ = Cypress.$
  $.extend(
    $.expr[':'], {
      idRegex: function(a, i, m) {
        const regex = new RegExp(m[3], 'i');
        return regex.test(a.getAttribute('id'));
      }
    }
  )

  const regex = 'item\\[\\d+\\].setupCost' 

  cy.get(`input:idRegex(${regex})`)
    .its('length')
    .should('eq', 3)   // ✅
})
```

Put the jQuery extension in `/cypress/support/index.js` to use it globally.

Note in the regex we have to double-escaped because we pass in a string not a regex.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of Regex you can use `^` with your selector. This denotes the start of the text. So you can write:

```js
cy.get('[id^="item"]')
```

Now if you want to access any particular element you can use `eq` like this:

```js
cy.get('[id^="item"]').eq(0) //gets id=item[0].setupCost
cy.get('[id^="item"]').eq(1) //gets id=item[1].setupCost
```

If you want to loop over each element you can use `each()`

```js
cy.get('[id^="item"]').each(($ele) => {
  cy.wrap($ele)
})
```

Answer (score 0):

You could create a custom Cypress command that would insert the index for you. Below, I'm assuming the `id` you're referencing is the ID of the element and is a standard CSS selector

```js
Cypress.Commands.add('getItemById', (index) => {
  return cy.get(`#item\\[${index}\\].setupCost`)
});


cy.getItemById(0)...
```

Comment: It's a great idea, but problem is `#item[` is looking for `<div id="item">` because `[` indicates start of an attribute selector. Would work with `[id="item[${index}]"`.

Comment: I made the assumption that they are using `id` as a standard attribute on the element, in which case the selectors `[id="item..."]` and `#item...` are equivalent. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/ID_selectors

Comment: Yeah, but try it...

Comment: Ah, so the issue isn't that `#item` is incorrect, it's that the brackets need escaping. I'll update my response.

Comment: Hmm, I tried that earlier - also with '\\\\' escaping but couldn't get it going.