# How to select an id with random number's by using Cypress

Tags: cypress

How would you find out if we know the name of the id but random numbers are displayed first before id's name like this   =>  5f15869ebc342_events_list.

`cy.get('button [id^="_events_list"]')`

I have tried this but isn't working.

I will be very thankful.

Comment: [^ means starts with](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Attribute_selectors) Have a look at what selectors are available to you at this link.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I user regex in cy.get()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71297568/how-can-i-user-regex-in-cy-get)

Answer (score 1):

As cloned points out, using `^` means you want the `id` to begin with `_events_list`. Instead, you can use either `$` to mean ends with, or `*` to mean contains to find your element.

```js
cy.get('button [id$="_events_list"]'); // $ for ends with

cy.get('button [id*="_events_list"]'); // * for contains
```

Comment: cy.get('.bp3-toast').find('*[id$="_events_list"]').click();  .   Thanks man this is working.